# pgn-extract: specify variation name when using --splitvariants flag

Tags: pgn

I'm using the --splitvariants flag to generate cards for anki, my problem is, how can i identify which line i'm playing? I though pgn-extract would have something like this, what i need is some way to append the variation name at the end of the line.

[image: multiple chess lines]

Please ignore the `false` keyword, what i need is to append a `;$VariantName` at the end of each line

Comment: There currently isn't a mechanism in pgn-extract for arbitrary output formats, but if you would like to contact me (the author of pgn-extract) via the email address that goes with the program then I will see if a custom solution might be possible for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For @kentdjb and anyone interesed I solved my issue by doing the following:

First I downloaded an eco.pgn containing the names of openings and variations. You can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/0izi8m8K)

Then I created an `args` file containing the following options:

```
:-C
:-e
:-w1000
:--minmoves 2
:-ofull-vienna.pgn
:--splitvariants
:--detag Event
:--detag Site
:--detag Date
:--detag White
:--detag Black
:--detag Result
:--detag ECO
:--detag Round
:--detag UTCDate
:--detag UTCTime
:--detag Annotator
:--detag Variant
```

Finally I ran the following command in my two pgn files containing vienna lines:

`$ pgn-extract {vienna-foobar1,vienna-foobar2}.pgn -Aargs` the output will throw something like this:

```
[Opening "Vienna gambit"]
[Variation "Paulsen attack"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nf6 3. f4 d5 4. fxe5 Nxe4 5. Qf3 Nxc3 6. bxc3 Be7 7. d4 O-O 8. Bd3 Be6 9. Ne2 c5 10. O-O Nc6 11. Be3 *
1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. Qg4 Qf6 5. Nd5 Qxf2+ 6. Kd1 Kf8 7. Nh3 h5 8. Qg5 f6 9. Qg6 Rh6 10. Ne7 *
1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Bc4 d6 4. d3 *
...
```

To convert this lines to anki cards I just use a vim macro to insert the `$Opening` and the `$Variation` at the end of each line.

Hope this is useful

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Often, post-processing pgn-extract output with another program is the best way to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for creating such an amazing program, it would be good if you could allow the `--detag` flag to receive multiple tags at one, like this: `--detag "tag1,tag2"`. At first i was using the `-Rtags --xroster` option but then i realize some games doesn't contain all the tags i specify inside the `tags` file

Comment: I'm glad you like the program. I could add something like that to --detag. I will put it on my list of improvements.